# Unwinding unvested shares bought at different prices when departing a company in California

Tags: united-states, options, employee-stock-options, option-exercise, vesting

My company repriced their options and the price dropped. Let's say the price went from $5 to $2 (not actual numbers).

I'd early-exercised 75% of my grant at $5 and (later) exercised the remaining portion at $2.

I'll be leaving the company; and they'll be unwinding half of the grant, so I'll get some money back, but now the question is: Do they pay me back from the $5 shares or the $2 shares?

Does the law require one or the other? Or is it up to them?

Answer (score 2):

> I'd early-exercised 75% of my grant at $5 and (later) exercised the remaining portion at $2.

So did you actually pay the money and got "X" unvested shares?

> I'll be leaving the company; and they'll be unwinding half of the grant, so I'll get some money back, but now the question is: Do they pay me back from the $5 shares or the $2 shares?

This would depend on what your contract says on unvested shares. There can be numerous combinations. More Often these are forfeited. i.e. you are not granted the shares. At times if you have paid then the guideline would give the details what would happen; i.e. only half vest and are priced at market and you are forced to encash them.